# How to void payments in Acumatica via API

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to make a web service call to Acumatica to void a a payment out, but I am unable to actually void the payments. Are there any options available through the web service call that is able to void payments?

Here is a piece of example code that I have that is as close as I can get to voiding a payment:

```
List<Command> cmds = new List<Command>();
        cmds.AddRange(new Command[] {
            new Value { Value = "Prepayment", LinkedCommand = AR302000.PaymentSummary.Type},
            new Value { Value = paymentID, LinkedCommand = AR302000.PaymentSummary.ReferenceNbr },
            AR302000.VoidCommandHere,
            AR302000.Actions.Save
        });
```

Comment: have you noticed AR302000.Actions.ReverseApplication and Actions.VoidCheck?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, but unfortunately it still did not work in my situation. It may have been do to the customizations in the screens that we have, but it did not effect the payment in any perceivable way.

Answer (score 0):

The Void action (`Actions.VoidCheck`) that you have in the AR Payments and Applications screen doesn't itself affect the original document. Instead, it creates an associated Void Payment document and redirects the user to it. The original payment is affected when this Void Payment is released.

Thus, what you may do is use the Void action to create the Void Payment and then release it through a separate API call - this should give you the desired result.